How to Integrate GridDB with Oracle APEX to Fetch and Display Data Dynamically?
I am working on an Oracle APEX application and want to integrate it with a GridDB database. My objective is to fetch data from GridDB and display it dynamically in an interactive report or classic report in APEX. However, I am facing challenges in establishing a connection and executing queries.
Here is what I have done so far:
I set up a GridDB container with the following schema:
CREATE TABLE SensorData (
    sensor_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    temperature FLOAT,
    humidity FLOAT
);

Insert data:
INSERT INTO SensorData VALUES (1, TIMESTAMP '2023-12-01 10:00:00', 25.5, 60.2);
INSERT INTO SensorData VALUES (2, TIMESTAMP '2023-12-01 10:05:00', 26.1, 61.0);
INSERT INTO SensorData VALUES (3, TIMESTAMP '2023-12-01 10:10:00', 24.8, 59.5);

In Oracle APEX, I created a RESTful Web Service to interact with the GridDB database. The Web Service is supposed to fetch the data as JSON and map it to an APEX report.
The GridDB REST API is accessible, and here’s an example of the response I get when querying data:
json
[
    {
        "sensor_id": 1,
        "timestamp": "2023-12-01T10:00:00",
        "temperature": 25.5,
        "humidity": 60.2
    },
    {
        "sensor_id": 2,
        "timestamp": "2023-12-01T10:05:00",
        "temperature": 26.1,
        "humidity": 61.0
    }
]

I created a REST Source in APEX to consume this JSON, but I’m struggling to map the fields correctly in the APEX Interactive Report.
My JSON parsing or mapping code:
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE(
    '[
        {"sensor_id": 1, "timestamp": "2023-12-01T10:00:00", "temperature": 25.5, "humidity": 60.2},
        {"sensor_id": 2, "timestamp": "2023-12-01T10:05:00", "temperature": 26.1, "humidity": 61.0}
    ]',
    '$[*]'
    COLUMNS (
        sensor_id NUMBER '$.sensor_id',
        timestamp TIMESTAMP '$.timestamp',
        temperature FLOAT '$.temperature',
        humidity FLOAT '$.humidity'
    )
);

Any code examples or detailed explanations would be greatly appreciated!
